# Xamarin Fragments with `NavigationView` no responding

Tags: xamarin.android

I am new in Xamarin.Android`development. 
I am trying to use`Fragments`with`NavigationView` but i have a problem 
when i clicking on item in navigationView i dont see any response (menu close automaticly & i dont see click effect)

Drawer Navigation Configuried in `MainActivity`

Main.axml

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/menu"       
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

  <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px" />
```

i tried to investigate this issue and
i thinking that something with menu items (null)
I attached a image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx8UO.jpg)

Comment: Could you also post the C# code-behind for the `MainActivity`? The problem is more likely there than in AXML

Comment: I Fixed the problem